# How do I maintain my column pattern during a df split?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to maintain the pattern of a column ('Item Type') when I split my dataframe. For example, this is my data:

[image: This is the sample of the column]

What I'm trying to achieve is for example: if I split after 10 rows, then I want to still include the 11th row since it is part of the pattern. The pattern here is one 'Product', `x` number of 'SKU' followed by `y` number of 'Rule'. Any split inside this pattern should include the whole pattern.

My current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("bracelet_no_variants.csv")
l=[i*1000 for i in range(len(df)//1000+1)]+[len(df)]
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    temp=df.iloc[l[i]:l[i+1]]
    temp.to_csv('bracelet_no_variants_'+str(l[i+1])+'.csv')
```

Would I have to add an if/else statement maybe?

Comment: use `dataframe,shift` to look at the next row, not a loop

Comment: @PaulH could you explain in more detail please, don't understand  exactly what you mean.

Comment: What is a pattern here? Simply that row 11 is the same as row 10?

Comment: @shaido I want the split to happen before there is a new product. So product, sku,sku, sku, sku, rule, rule, rule, rule. Split here before the next product comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general solution that given a number of rows, will find the next row with 'Product' and then include all rows up-to that point.

For example, given `n=7`:

```
n = 7
df_after = df.iloc[n:]
new_idx = df_after.loc[df_after['Item Type'] == 'Product'].index[0]
res = df.loc[:new_idx].iloc[:-1]
```

Will give:

```
    Item Type
1     Product
2         SKU
3         SKU
4         SKU
5         SKU
6         SKU
7        Rule
8        Rule
9        Rule
10       Rule
11       Rule
```

This code should work independently of the index values, i.e., the index can be anything as long as there are no duplicates.